# Selecting tab as default jquery

Tags: jquery

Thanks to  JAAulde for update. Sitll having some issues.

```
$( function()
{
var tabs = $( 'ul.sideMenu a' ),
    selected,
    hashes = [],
    tabContainers;

tabs.each( function()
{
    var locationhash, linkhash, selectthis;

    locationhash = ( window.location.hash !== '' ) ? window.location.hash : '#index';
    linkhash = this.hash;

    if( this.pathname === window.location.pathname )
    {
        hashes.push( linkhash );

        selectthis = ( linkhash === locationhash );

        $( this ).toggleClass( 'selected', selectthis );
        $( linkhash ).toggle( selectthis );
    }
} );

tabContainers = $( hashes.join( ', ' ) );

tabs.bind( 'click', function( e )
{
    // hide all tabs
    tabContainers
        .hide()
        .filter( this.hash )
            .show();

    // set up the selected class
    tabs.removeClass( 'selected bluecolor' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'selected bluecolor' );

    e.preventDefault()
} );
} );
```

Menu --
    
       
           URL
       
       
           URL

Content --

```
<div id="URL">content</div>
<div id="Content2">content2</div>
```

So I still can't get it to select the first tab on page load. Instead its loading a blank page.

I am also having bugs in IE "Message: 'this.style' is null or not an object
Line: 30
Char: 9"
In IE the whole page loads and when I click links it only acts like an anchor. This is driving me crazy. Any help greatly appreciated. If I get it working I'll update here.

Comment: do you use jqueryui .tabs() ?

Comment: I am new to jquery so I am unsure if thats what I am using here. Otherwise, no.

Comment: so check this : http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: I went with .tabs()  was way easier. I just had to edit out most of the css file styles but after that it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that at document ready you're targeting `ul.sideMenu a`. But your code shows an `LI` with `ID` set to `sideMenu` (as opposed to class).

Match up your selector element/specifiers with what's in the DOM, or post code which gives better context.

**Edit:** based on your responses the markup is fine and your click section is working. So now you need to determine during load what the browser is loading, and when you see a link which matches that you need to select it. The code I give below should work for you or get you moving where you want to be.  I think there are better ways to write it but I wanted to avoid too much modification to your code so that it is somewhat recognizable to you. Personally I prefer using jQuery UI for things like this. But if this is the only thing UI provides which you would be using, then it's probably overkill.

**Code:**

```
$( function()
{
    var tabs = $( 'ul.sideMenu a' ),
        selected,
        hashes = [],
        tabContainers;

    tabs.each( function()
    {
        var locationhash, linkhash, selectthis;

        locationhash = ( window.location.hash !== '' ) ? window.location.hash : '#index';
        linkhash = this.hash;

        if( this.pathname === window.location.pathname )
        {
            hashes.push( linkhash );

            selectthis = ( linkhash === locationhash );

            $( this ).toggleClass( 'selected', selectthis );
            $( linkhash ).toggle( selectthis );
        }
    } );

    tabContainers = $( hashes.join( ', ' ) );

    tabs.bind( 'click', function( e )
    {
        // hide all tabs
        tabContainers
            .hide()
            .filter( this.hash )
                .show();

        // set up the selected class
        tabs.removeClass( 'selected' );
        $( this ).addClass( 'selected' );

        e.preventDefault()
    } );
} );
```

Comment: this does not matter.  "ul.sideMenu a" will list all the <a>s in ul.sideMenu whether or not they are in an li element

Comment: @Joseph - do you see a `UL` with class of `sideMenu` in his given markup?  That's my point.  I see no such `UL` with such a class--I see `LI`s with an `ID` (of the same value which he's using as a class in the selector) instead. And just in case he does, indeed, have such a UL that's why I said "or post code which gives better context."

Comment: aha good catch.  It needs to be `ul #sideMenu a` in that case or just `#sideMenu a`

Comment: I have the UL class as side menu
                     <ul class="sideMenu">

What would I add so the first item is selected? Should I modify the <li> attribute to something else?

Comment: Ok, since you report that the click section works and that the markup is fine, I got past my initial issues and took a closer look. During the initial setup (where you `.each()` the links), you need to determine if one of the links points at the same thing the browser is currently showing. If it does, you need to do ahead and select it. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help JAAulde. This is now hiding inactive tabs, but still not loading the first. The landing link is index.php?#URL but it won't show that section, just a blank section. I tried changing the `#index` to `#URL` with no effect.

I think its because the link that loads the first instance of the page is outside of the `sideMenu` class. 

Can I add a class to each first item `class="first"` and have the script detect that somehow and load the tab?

Comment: The fact that you're trying to do this tabbing thing, but want stuff outside the tabs to have an effect, makes it difficult for me to envision.  Could you produce a minimal version as a stand alone HTML document and pastie it somewhere?

Comment: Well, what I want is the first tab to be selected when the page loads. I dont think its outside of the tabs. I tried setting up a simple example but its giving me issues.

Comment: Something like     `tabs:last.addClass("selected bluecolor");`

Comment: Updated above having issues in IE.

Answer (score 0):

In your code this.pathname and this.hash will not give anything because this is an anchor object which do not have this attributes by default. Try this

```
$(function () {
    var tabs = [];
    var tabContainers = [];
    $('ul.sideMenu a').each(function () {
        // note that this only compares the pathname, not the entire url
        // which actually may be required for a more terse solution.
        if (window.location.pathname.indexOf(this.href) != -1) {
            tabs.push(this);
            tabContainers.push(this.href.split("#")[1]).get(0));
        }
    });
    $(tabs).click(function () {
        // hide all tabs
        $("#"+tabContainers).hide().filter("#"+this.href.split("#")[1]).show();

        // set up the selected class
        $(tabs).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. My current script works fine..except when the pages load. Then it shows everything, otherwise when you click the first sideMenu link it breaks it apart and only displays the item its suppose to.

My problem is getting it to display only the first item on each page when the page first loads without a click

Answer (score 0):

I have a Tab system that I think is similar to yours. The code that I use is based on filters, associating different classes to the contents of different tabs.

JS / jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            fillConfeRegList(getEventID()); // Fill the contents (Must use your code to fill the container)
            // Set the default tab VISIBLE
            applyFilter('pendente');
        });

        function applyFilter(state){
            $('#inscContainer .item').each(function(index){
                (!$(this).hasClass(state))?$(this).hide():$(this).show();
            });

            $('#filterControl .filterTab').each(function(index){
                ($(this).hasClass('filter-'+state))?$(this).addClass("currentFilter"):$(this).removeClass("currentFilter");
            });

        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="filterControl">
    <input type="button" id="cmdFilterItemsAll" class="filterTab filter-item" onclick="javascript:applyFilter('item');" value="Ver Todos" />                 
    <input type="button" id="cmdFilterItemsPendentes" class="filterTab filter-pendente currentFilter" onclick="javascript:applyFilter('pendente');" value="Ver Pendentes" />                 
    <input type="button" id="cmdFilterItemsProcessado" class="filterTab filter-processado" onclick="javascript:applyFilter('processado');" value="Ver Processados" />
 </div>
 <div id="inscContainer" style="display: block; ">&nbsp;</div>
```